# Create new column storing average of rows from another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I am trying to create a new column that has stores the 'Average weight of the field'. For example, the answer for RaceID = 123 would be 54.5. The RaceID's are not organised from smaller to largest and are displayed randomly like the example below.

| RaceID | Weight | No. Starters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 56 | 2 |
| 124 | 58 | 2 |
| 123 | 53 | 2 |
| 125 | 60 | 2 |
| 125 | 51 | 2 |
| 124 | 62 | 2 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query, It will display current table data along with average column :

```
select t.*,
avg(Weight) over(partition by raceID order by raceID ) avg_raceID
from table t;
```

Comment: I upvoted, but FWIW the `order by raceID` is superfluous. Order of rows in the window doesn't matter for `average()` and also the value will be uniform within each window because it's the partition column.

Comment: Also the window function is `avg()`, not `average()`.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes, I modified the function moreover that's true order is not have much significance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RaceID, AVG(Weight) AS val_1
FROM dataset_name
GROUP BY RaceID;
```

By using above code we can get the average value of weights for every unique RaceID. Check the below image for better understanding.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMA68.png
Let me know if there are any modifications or error.